# Как дополнить case уникальным значением

Tags: oracle, plsql

Нужно в  `sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001') THEN 1 END) f22` добавить условие `COUNT(DISTINCT p.date_input)`, т.е. что-то подобное

```
sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001') and p.date_input(Уникальные) THEN 1 END) f22
```

где `p.date_input` формат `DATE`,

и аналогично
`sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001')  THEN 1 END) f23` добавить условие `COUNT(DISTINCT p.username)`

где `p.username` формат `VARCHAR`

также, подобное

```
sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001') and p.username(Уникальные) THEN 1 END) f23
```

Запрос

```
select 
    --w.mo f1,
     nvl (w.mo, (select mo from t_mo t where t.mo_id=1)) f1,       
    ''f2,
    '0'f3, 
    ' 'f4, 
            sum(case when t.regname=p.username or t.regname!=p.username THEN 1 END) f5,
            sum(case when t.regname=p.username THEN 1 END) f6,
            sum(case when t.regname!=p.username THEN 1 END) f7,

            sum(case when p.cause_id IN (22,1) THEN 1 END) f8, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (24,23,25,3,2,4) THEN 1 END) f9, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (26,5) THEN 1 END) f10, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (27,6) THEN 1 END) f11, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (28,8) THEN 1 END) f12, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (29,9,32,36) THEN 1 END) f13, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (30,10) THEN 1 END) f14, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (31,11) THEN 1 END) f15, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (33,13) THEN 1 END) f16, 
            sum(case when cause_id in (34,35,7,15,12,14) THEN 1 END) f17,
            sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001') THEN 1 END) f18,
            sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34002') THEN 1 END) f19,
            sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34004') THEN 1 END) f20,
            sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34') THEN 1 END) f21,
       --new     
          sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001')  THEN 1 END) f22,
          sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001')  THEN 1 END) f23 
            
from  t_block_ger t, t_petit p, t_mo w   WHERE t.id_ger=p.id
  AND p.mo_id=w.mo_id
  AND p.conect_id=5
  AND to_date(t.date_end) BETWEEN '01.01.2022' AND '01.05.2022'
  group by w.mo
  --order by f1
  
union all

select 
''f1,                  
''f2,
'0'f3,
' 'f4,
 count(case when t.regname=p.username or t.regname!=p.username THEN 1 END) f5,
 count(case when t.regname=p.username THEN 1 END) f6,
 count(case when t.regname!=p.username THEN 1 END) f7,
 count(case when p.cause_id IN (22,1) THEN 1 END) f8, 
 count(case when cause_id in (24,23,25,3,2,4) THEN 1 END) f9, 
 count(case when cause_id in (26,5) THEN 1 END) f10, 
 count(case when cause_id in (27,6) THEN 1 END) f11, 
 count(case when cause_id in (28,8) THEN 1 END) f12, 
 count(case when cause_id in (29,9,32,36) THEN 1 END) f13, 
 count(case when cause_id in (30,10) THEN 1 END) f14, 
 count(case when cause_id in (31,11) THEN 1 END) f15, 
 count(case when cause_id in (33,13) THEN 1 END) f16, 
 count(case when cause_id in (34,35,7,15,12,14) THEN 1 END) f17,
 count(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001') THEN 1 END) f18,
 count(case when p.otv_kon in ('34002') THEN 1 END) f19,
 count(case when p.otv_kon in ('34004') THEN 1 END) f20,
 count(case when p.otv_kon in ('34') THEN 1 END) f21,
--new 
sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001') THEN 1 END) f22, 
sum(case when p.otv_kon in ('34001')  THEN 1 END) f23


 from  t_block_ger t, t_petit p, t_mo w   WHERE t.id_ger=p.id
  AND p.mo_id=w.mo_id
  AND p.conect_id=5 AND P.TYPE_ID in(1,3)
  AND to_date(t.date_end) BETWEEN '01.01.2022' AND '01.05.2022'
order by f1
```

Comment: Описывайте задачу, а не только попытку её решить. *добавить условие `COUNT(DISTINCT p.date_input)`* - это не условие, а просто выражение (которое, впрочем, может использоваться как условие, ибо приводится к булеву типу - но для именно этого выражения подобное абсолютно бессмысленно).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.otv_kon IN ('34001') THEN p.date_input END) AS f22
```

Comment: -при p.date_input
ORA-00932:несовместимые типы данных: ожидается NUMBER, получено DATE
-при p.username
ORA-01722: неверное число

Comment: @wq55 поправил на COUNT, попробуй

Comment: Спасибо Большое! Получилось.